# How do I shuffle a file in one-line ruby -e

Tags: ruby

I have the following file:

```
A
B
C
...
```

I want `ruby -e` to read the file, shuffle it, and standard output it, like so for example:

```
P
C
A
...
```

How do I do this. So far, I've gotten to `ruby -e 'puts $_' filename.txt`.

Comment: ``ruby -e 'puts `shuf`' < filename.txt`` :)

Comment: @Ry- hahaha! Smart, but that doesn't work on MacOS :) Check my own answer please, I think it'll work anywhere Ruby does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can read all lines from [`ARGF`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/ARGF.html) into an array:

```
ruby -e 'puts $<.to_a.shuffle' filename.txt
```

or by splatting the lines to make it extra short:

```
ruby -e'puts [*$<].shuffle' filename.txt
```

It’ll also accept input on stdin with no filename.

Comment: ARGF also works with my answer below for the same reason :) but your solution is shorter and easier to read!

Comment: Could you elaborate why you used the splat operator (`*`) and wrapped it in an array (`[...]`)? ("I don’t know a lot of Ruby", he says)

Comment: @UpvoteMe: It ended up one character shorter than `.to_a`. I didn’t know it existed, but it does in Python, so I tried it :D

Comment: Oh, right! Because you need to convert it into an array before you shuffle it, which `$<` is not :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a test file:

```
str = "three\nblind\nmice\n"
File.write('data_in', str)
  #= 17
```

From the command line.

If not limited to Ruby<sup>1</sup>:

```
cat data_in|shuf
mice
three
blind
```

Using Ruby,

```
ruby -e "puts STDIN.readlines.shuffle.join" < data_in
mice
blind
three
```

or

```
ruby -e "puts ARGF.readlines.shuffle.join" data_in
blind
mice
three
```

<sup>1 See [doc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/shuf.1.html). This doesn't work with OS X, but there's a [fix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142860/install-shuf-on-os-x).</sup>

Comment: Hi, while this solution works, it requires multiple different executions, creates a temporary file, requires a temporary file, and as of now doesn't clean up after creating the temporary file :). While it's "one-line", it's also one line, but executed multiple times. It works, but not according to what the question asked, which was "`ruby -e` to read the file, shuffle it, and standard output it" :) Thank you for your help though!

Comment: The above comment pertains to my original answer, which reflected a misreading of the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
ruby -ne 'BEGIN { data = [] }; data << $_; END {puts data.shuffle}' filename.txt
```

This does the following:

- Add the `-n` flag, which wraps the input in `while gets(); ... end;`
- Use `BEGIN` to create an initial `data` variable that's shared across every loop run
- Shovels the data into the `data` variable on every loop
- Use `END` to output that final `data` variable.